Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid items with same height having different number of Subview without giving a fixed height
I am trying to achieve a LazyVerticalGrid of GridCells.Fixed(2). The problem I am facing is with the item.
My GridItem has components(views) that vary on the conditions. For example, if some data is unavailable do not show that particular item(view).
I want each GridItem to be the same size, whichever is bigger of the two items.
I do not want to set a fixed height of the Grid item.
Here is what it looks like now

What I am expecting  (to showcase the expected example, I have set a fixed height )

Here is my code. It's a pretty basic implementation ->
@Composable
fun DynamicHeightGrid(items: List = listOf(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)) {
LazyVerticalGrid(
columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
modifier = Modifier
.padding(16.dp)
) {
    itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
        GridItem(item)
    }
}

}
@Composable
fun GridItem(
content: RandomItems,
) {
Card(
modifier = Modifier
.padding(4.dp)
.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier`enter code here`
            .padding(4.dp)

    ) {
        with(content) {
            //     Text(text = "$index height $height", fontSize = 20.sp, maxLines = 3)

            Text(text = title!!, fontSize = 20.sp, maxLines = 3)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))

            Text(text = " Price: $price!!", fontSize = 24.sp)


            value?.let {
                Text(text = value, fontSize = 14.sp)
            }

            Text(text = shortDesc!!, fontSize = 14.sp)

            passion?.let {
                Text(text = passion, fontSize = 14.sp)
            }

            newValue?.let {
                Text(text = newValue, fontSize = 14.sp)
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            if (isRequired == true) {
                Button(
                    onClick = { },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(20.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Red)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        color = Color.White,
                        text = "Get New value"
                    )
                }
            }


        }

    }
}

}
What I have tried :
How to level the height of items in LazyVerticalGrid?
Jetpack Compose: Row with all items same height

Figured out a solution :
@Composable
fun GridViewWithSameItemHeight() {
    val listItems: List<RandomItems> = listOf(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
    
LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = (LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp - 32).dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {

        var index = 0
        items(listItems.size / 2) {
            val firstIndex = index * 2
            val secondIndex = firstIndex + 1

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                val cardWidth = (LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp - 48) / 2
                FirstGridItem(width = cardWidth.dp, listItems[firstIndex])
                SecondGridItem(width = cardWidth.dp, listItems[secondIndex])
            }
            index++
        }
    }
}

Two things that solved the problem are:
1- Row with two items and set the height of wor to IntrinsicSize.Max
2- Set column to columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = (LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp - 32).dp)
